# Thymeleaf 3.0 template engine that picks up templates from two locations

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, view, thymeleaf

I am setting up a custom template engine that should process templates from two locations.. How do i setup a custom template engine that can achieve this?

Ok so, the engine should deal only with thymeleaf templates and pick them up from two different locations. One of them is the usual /WEB-INF/templates but the other one should be outside app context and in the filesystem For the sake of the argument let it be on D:/apps/myapp/instances/ . For the filesystem one i managed to process the template with FileTemplateResolver, and for the internal templates ClassLoaderTemplateResolver which is no good because I've read that Thymeleaf 3.0 uses SpringResourceTemplateResolver. Apart from this problem i have another one, i am unable to make the engine process both, it can be either one or another based on order. Check my code

```
        @Bean
    public TemplateEngine templateEngine() {
      SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new 
          SpringTemplateEngine();

      templateEngine.setEnableSpringELCompiler(true);
      templateEngine.addTemplateResolver(thymeleafTemplateResolver());
      templateEngine.addTemplateResolver(databaseTemplateResolver());

      return templateEngine;
    }

    //Resolver for thymeleaf
    @Bean
    public ThymeleafViewResolver  thymeleafViewResolver() {
        ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setTemplateEngine((ISpringTemplateEngine) templateEngine());
        viewResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        viewResolver.setOrder(0);
        viewResolver.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);

        return viewResolver;
    }
    //Pulling out methods
    @Bean(name = "databaseTemplateResolver")
    public ITemplateResolver databaseTemplateResolver() {
        var prefix = rootDirectory+Directory.INSTANCES_DIR+File.separator;
        System.out.println(prefix);
        var templateResolver 
          = new FileTemplateResolver();
        templateResolver.setPrefix(prefix);
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        templateResolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
        templateResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        templateResolver.setOrder(1);
        templateResolver.setCacheable(false);
        return templateResolver;
    }
    @Bean(name = "thymeleafTemplateResolver")
    public ITemplateResolver thymeleafTemplateResolver() {
        var templateResolver 
          = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();
      templateResolver.setPrefix("templates/");

       // var templateResolver   = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
      //  templateResolver.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        //templateResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/templates/");
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        templateResolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
        templateResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        templateResolver.setCacheable(false);
        templateResolver.setOrder(0);
        return templateResolver;
    }
```

If the order is set to 0 for ThymeleafTemplateResolver and 1 for databaseTemplateResolver i will get

```
        org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "templates/europe/fra-1/offer.html")
at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parse(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:235) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parseStandalone(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:100) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.parseAndProcess(TemplateManager.java:666) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar:3.0.11.RELEASE]
```

when trying to load filesystem template and the internal template will load without css for some reason

If the order is set to 1 for ThymeleafTemplateResolver and 0 for databaseTemplateResolver i will get

```
       org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "D:\apps\myapp\instances\login.html")
org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parse(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:235)
org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parseStandalone(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:100)
org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.parseAndProcess(TemplateManager.java:666)
```

When trying to load internal template, but the filesystem template will load just fine.

For some reason template engine picks up only one resolver and doesn't check the other. How can i resolve these issues and make the template engine process both?

Thanks!

Comment: I think the SpringResolver supports all Spring Resource patterns. Have you tried classpath:something and file:///absolutepath as resource patterns?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i've managed to set it up with Spring resource!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you set `setCheckExistence(true)` on one of your resolvers (the resolver that happens first with the lower order number), it will throw an exception when it can't find the template.  [See the documentation for chaining resolvers](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#chaining-template-resolvers).

Comment: Thanks for you reply, i managed to set it up with this! Also i've added patterns to the template resolvers to make searching and matching quicker. Thanks again!!